# Hadoop HDFS Namenode Failing

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I am having a serious issue when restarting the Namenode role in my master node.

`May 27, 4:50:09.866 PM ERROR   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode 
RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM 
May 27, 4:50:10.182 PM  INFO    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode 
SHUTDOWN_MSG:`

As it can be seen, the process is receiving a SIGTERM and the Namenode is being shutdown.

Does anyone have any idea on what is going on?

Which logs should I look into in order to debug the problem that is causing the SIGTERM?

I am using Cloudera Manager. (Cloudera Express 5.5.1)

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest `clousters->HDFS->Instances->NameNode(Active)->LogFiles`, check the log files

- Role log file
- Stdout
- Stderr

Hope this helps you find some clues.

And `HDFS->Configuration->Scope(NameNode)->Category(log)`

change this **NameNode Logging Threshold** choose **TRACE** as an option to find out more.